# need for json loader in webpack 5

Tags: javascript, json, webpack, geojson

I want to import `.geojson` file extension just like `.json` files (I don't need any special parsing).
as I seen in webpack docs:

> Since webpack >= v2.0.0, importing of JSON files will work by default.
> **You might still want to use this if you use a custom file extension**.
> See the v1.0.0 -> v2.0.0 Migration Guide for more information

but when I switch documentation version to webpack 5, there is no more content about this solution.

what is best practice to have `.geojson` files without downloading any extra module

Comment: Try reading the file using the `fs` module, then use something like `JSON.parse`

Comment: @kerolloz does it helps for bundling? I want to host my final project in a web server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In webpack 5 we can use "Asset Modules" to load common files like "json", "png" etc.
See for more info: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

The loader config for your case might looks like this:

```js
{
    test: /\.geojson$/,
    type: 'json',
}
```