# How to load a .geojson file in TypeScript with webpack?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I need data from a `.geojson` file. I tried two things:

```
const geojson = require('../../assets/mygeojson.geojson');
```

This failed with the following error:

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:6)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

My second approach was to use the following:

```
const geojson = await (await fetch('../../assets/mygeojson.geojson')).json();
```

This failed with the following error:

> Module parse failed: The top-level-await experiment is not enabled (set experiments.topLevelAwait: true to enabled it)
> File was processed with these loaders:
>
> - ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
> - ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js

I don't know where exactly to enable those experiments mentioned in the error message.

In any event, all I need is the GeoJSON file as a plain JSON object for further use in my code. Is there perhaps a third approach so simply load a file in TypeScript?

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73531293/12888769) from @jneuendorf is great. If you're also using regular json, combining the two in your module/rules via regex cleaned the code up a bit. This also works for other assets. Yay modularity!

```
// JSON (requires loader): npm install --save-dev json-loader
{
    test: /\.(json|geojson)$/,
    loader: 'json-loader'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72027753/6928824) solved the problem:

```
{
    test: /\.geojson$/,
    type: 'json',
}
```